# Get-ACL Returning Null Values with Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

So I have a script here that is meant to remotely get a listing of all the files in a directory along with some basic information.

$a is the computer name, `$b` is the file path, `$d` is the output file name (predetermined), and `$e` is the output type.

```
$script = (invoke-command -ComputerName $a -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {param($path) get-childitem -Force -literalpath $path} -ArgumentList $b) 

switch ($e)
{
    json
    {
        $script | select Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,Length,Mode, @{n="Owner";e={(Get-Acl -LiteralPath $_.fullname).owner}} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | Out-File $outputfilepath\"$d".json
    }
    csv
    {
        $script | select Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,Length,Mode, @{n="Owner";e={(Get-Acl -LiteralPath $_.fullname).owner}} | ConvertTo-Csv | Out-File $outputfilepath\"$d".csv
    }
}
```

My problem is this the "Owner" property that gets returned by Get-ACL is always returning either **null** or "**`builtin\administrators`**", instead of the actual owner. When I run the exact same command (minus all the fluff) on my local machine, it returns the proper user as the owner for all the files. However once I use the script to run it against something remote, the ownership data stops being correct.

The credentials I am using should not have any permission issues, so I am confused as to why I am not pulling the correct data.

Comment: But the files on your local machine are not the remote files. The proper test would be to RDP over to the remote machines and issue those commands locally and *then* establish whether the result is correct or not. Also, if I'm not misreading what you're doing, you're running `Get-Acl` directly on a remote file -- how are you expecting that to work? What's in `$_.fullname`? Shouldn't you be doing `Get-ACL` *within* the `Invoke-Command`?

Comment: So when my coworker runs the commands (`Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\coworker\Desktop\" | select Name,CreationTime,LastWriteTime,Length,Mode, @{n="Owner";e={(Get-Acl $_.fullname).owner}}
` on his machine locally, he gets the expected result: he is listed as the owner for most files (DOMAIN\coworker).

When I use the script to inspect the same directory, there is nothing returned in the Owner field, or it is listed as the builtin\administrators user.

Comment: My point is that you are not inspecting the same files if you use `Invoke-Command` to get a remote file list, but then run `Get-Acl` locally, *supplying it the names of the remote files*. It'll try to get the ACL of the file as it exists on your machine, which I'd expect to fail with "does not exist" in most cases, or at least give back the wrong owner.

Comment: I understand what you mean now. I haven't encountered this issue on other scripts I have that used the same basic structure, so it was unexpected.

How would I pass that to the Invoke-Command block then? Can I just pipe the Select and Get-ACL portions onto the end like `$script = (invoke-command -ComputerName $a -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {param($path) Get-ChildItem -Force -LiteralPath $path | select Name, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, Length, Mode, @{n="Owner";e={(Get-Acl $_.Name).owner}} } -ArgumentList $b) `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by editing my Invoke-Command to work like the below, moving the Select statement and the Get-ACL up into the block itself

```
$script = (invoke-command -ComputerName $a -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {param($path) Get-ChildItem -Force -LiteralPath $path | select Name, CreationTime, LastWriteTime, Length, Mode, @{Label=”Owner”; Expression={(Get-ACL ($path+$_.Name)).Owner}} } -ArgumentList $b)
```

And then my conversions into

```
$script | ConvertTo-Json -Compress | Out-File $outputfilepath\"$d".json
```