# get-acl access property is just System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule when run inside invoke-command

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, invoke-command

I'm tying to get the permissions of all the folders in a path on a remote server as efficiently as I can so I want to make as few calls as I can (avoiding looping through all folders and running a get-acl call for each). I'm running the following command in a powershell remote session $Session

```
$ACL = Invoke-command -Session $Session -Scriptblock{get-childitem -path "drive:\folderpath" | GET-ACL}
```

However once I try to use the object to look at the access list with `$ACL.access` then all folders just say `System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule` and have no properties.

If instead I run the below then `$ACLAccess` shows the permissions as I would expect.

```
$ACLAccess = Invoke-command -Session $Session -Scriptblock{(get-childitem -path "drive:\folderpath" | GET-ACL).access}
```

Why is the access property displaying differently inside invoke-command compared to outside of invoke-command?

This [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49453551/get-acl-returning-null-values-with-invoke-command) does not answer why getting the property inside the invoke seems to work but outside doesn't.

Comment: What happens if you try to get `$ACL.AccessRule` instead of just access?

Comment: The difference is that PowerShell needs to serialize (ie. "turn into text") the data from the remote session, and as a result the object(s) you receive on the client side have none of their original methods attached anymore - including the methods PowerShell would call when invoking the `Access` ETS property.

Comment: Ah OK so I'm not actually getting all of the original object back from invoke-command. Any way to stop the serialisation for that property or make sure that the info I want makes it through?

Comment: Maybe try `... | Get-Acl | Select *, @{ N='Access' ; E={$_.Access}}`